# Como posso relacionar 3 campo ao post no Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Tenho um campo personalizado cujo nome é **tipo de veículo**. Esse campo recebe os tipos *carro* ou *moto*. Fiz um combo select com `jQuery` que, quando seleciono o tipo do veículo, é preenchido com a marca do veículo. Por exemplo: `tipo = moto > marca = Honda`. Até aí tudo bem. Só que quando seleciono a marca para ele retornar o modelo em um terceiro select, que é relacionado ao modelo, ele não retornar nada!

O campo para o tipo do veículo é um campo personalizado. Para a marca, uso uma categoria, e para o modelo, outro campo personalizado!

Existe uma forma melhor para relacionar esses três campos?

Comment: Poste parte do código para facilitar.

Comment: Até dava para tentar ajudar, mas sem código fica dificil dizer qualquer coisa...